# Dell 7559 15.10 version hangs while booting Live version

Tags: wireless, graphics, 15.10

I need to install Ubuntu/xubuntu alongside with Windows. 
Ubuntu 14.04 boots live version fine and I am able to install it. But once upgraded it freezes randomly. I have tried ctrl+del+reisub and other methods described. But it didn't work.  Restart is the only way I found. 
Alsomy WiFi card,  Intel 3165 was not detected .  so I upgraded to kernel 4.1. The kernel upgrade doesn't boot and gives the error "system is running o. Low graphics mode"  . but it doent go anywhere from there.

So I tried 15.10 on Ubuntu and xubuntu. 
When I load live usb (used LiLi) 
Both show the OS symbol a d the leading symbol moves and after a while it freezes.

Need help pls !

FYI
Graphics card :
Nvidia graphics 960M

Win 10 already installed

Answer (score 1):

I installed Xunbuntu 15.10 on DELL i7559.

1. On the GRUB menu, press 'e'.
2. On the line that starts by 'linux', insert  'nomodeset' after 'splash'.
3. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.
4. Install Xubuntu from the desktop.

Again, before starting Xubuntu for the first time, modify the GRUB boot like previously. After rebooting, go to Additional Drivers in Settings and select one of the NVIDIA binary driver. I tried all of them and none of them works perfectly but they work. Reboot again but this time do not add nomodeset.

Now, here is the issue with the NVIDIA binary driver: when the computer wakes up from sleeping mode, it freezes.

The only way, I found to avoid this problem, it is unfortunately to use the Intel integrated graphic cpu instead of the NVIDIA graphic card. For this, in the Additional Drivers, select:

```
X.Org X Server-- Nouveau display driver...
```

and reboot. With this driver, the computer does not freeze when it wakes up but the NVIDIA card is not used.

Other issues:

- Wifi does not start automatically when it comes back from sleeping mode.
- The battery life is around 4 hours but it is around 8 hours under Windows.
- Errors messages when rebooting.

Otherwise, all the features of the computer work.

In conclusion, I still use Xubuntu but I am disappointing by the issues mentioned above and also to see Windows more efficient on this computer than Linux. I am waiting for the version 16.04 to see if the issues will be fixed. If not, I think to eventually move to Windows.

Answer (score 1):

For your nvidia graphics card follow this
After booting into Xubuntu
Ctrl + Alt + F1(anything from F1 to F6)
and then

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot 

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
sudo reboot
```

This will install the right version of nvidia graphics card.